# Is it possible to use google reCaptcha in a form made in elm

Tags: forms, elm, recaptcha

I would like to add a contact form to my website made in `elm` (version 0.18).
In order to prevent abusing spamming by bots I am thinking about integrating a captcha verification plugin in it, specifically google invisible reCaptcha, or the slightly [older](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) version where you have to click "I am not a Robot"

From what I understand from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible), in order to use these I have either to add some attributes to the form submit button, or call it from a javascript method.

The problem is since I use the [elm Http](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest) module to process the form in app
 I have no button whith a `type="submit"` attribute, and I don't know how to call the google plug-in API from my elm code.

Is this possible? Or is this any other method more `elm` friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may need to use the explicit rendering for reCAPTCHA (see https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render)

I have a basic example setup at https://ellie-app.com/SyRXChQbYqa1/1

Answer (score 3):

Adding attributes to your buttons is actually quite easy in Elm.  Take a look at [Html.Attributes.attribute](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/latest/Html-Attributes#attribute).  To get a basic submit button, just do this:

```
button [ attribute "type" "submit" ] [ text "Submit!" ]
```

Concerning the google reCaptcha in particular... I don't have the ability to actually toy with google's api right now, but I believe that you should be able to make a [port](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) that can function as the `data-callback` field's value.  What follows is basically idle speculation because I'm on mobile, so take it with a grain of salt...

Declare an appropriate port (pretty sure the callback just gets passed a string, but perhaps you'll need to change that):

```
port captcha_port : ( String -> Msg ) -> Sub Msg
```

Add a button with google's required attributes, including the send function of your newly created port:

```
button
  [ attribute "class" "g-recaptcha"
  , attribute "data-sitekey" "your_site_key"
  , attribute "data-callback" "app.ports.captcha_port.send"
  ] [ text "Sumbit All The Things!" ]
```

And subscribe to the port with an appropriate `Msg` type somewhere in your `subscriptions` function:

```
captcha_port CaptchEvent
```

Comment: I tried adding a port like you said but I don't get anything back. I just don't get how this thing is supposed to work (google reCaptcha, not elm) There seem to be several ways to invoke the captcha widget, and depending if the attributes are in a div or a button, the callback function is supposed to call grecaptcha.execute() or grecaptcha.render() or maybe both. Moreover I would like to process the g-recaptcha-response in app, not on the server, and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @fayonglin, I don't think it's possible to process the CAPTCHA response on the client, because then a malicious client could just bypass CAPTCHA altogether.  From what I understand, it _has_ to go through a server validation.

Comment: @bdukes from google: When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll get as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". In order to check whether Google has verified that user, send a POST request with these parameters: [..] Even if I do the last verification server side I think I still need a way to get the "g-recaptcha-response" to the server sent from my elm app as json, without using the classic html submit behaviour.